# How to use ConditionalRouter mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to call different sequence according to some number range( Here is technical purpose). Here is my condition

Case 01.

```
number = 100  then call  sequence01
```

Case 02

```
100<number<200 then call sequence2
```

Case 03

```
200<number<300 then call sequence3
```

I tried with using **Filter mediator**. But it's big code. I need to do this with some simple way more than filter mediator. I tried to use **ConditionalRouter** mediator to do this task according to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Endpoint+Error+Handling) documentation. But I don't have idea how to apply this to my task. Can I use ConditionalRouter mediator to solve my task.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily achieve this by using the [switch mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Switch+Mediator).

```
<switch source="get-property('propertyCotainingValue')">
               <case regex="\d\d">
                  <!-- call sequence 1-->
               </case>
               <case regex="1\d\d">
                    <!-- call sequence 2-->
               </case>
               <case regex="2\d\d">
                    <!-- call sequence 3-->
               </case>
               <default>
               </default>
            </switch>
```

Comment: 100<number<200 gives  boolien value. true or false can we check this(like boolien condition) using switch mediator

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t understand your question. If the regex defined in "case" (you can also use xpath here) matches, the mediators or whatever you define inside the "case" will be executed.